# Dynamically add Crystal Report Header(s) and chart(s) based on a count

Tags: charts, crystal-reports

I am working on a Crystal Report that is utilizing the Multiple Pie Chart graph type to show some data on change of location. I have run into the situation where a record has 17 locations. I cannot seem to make the chart auto-grow, even though set to only display 2 pies per row, it is showing all 17 pie charts on a single page. This is way too dense. I think the answer would be to count the data-rows involved and dynamically insert a Report Header and single Pie Chart for each, but have no idea how to accomplish this in Crystal. I have spent quite a bit of time looking for information on this and come up with absolutely nothing. I'm pretty much a CR newb. Haven't worked with it since school, years ago. A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you show image how it is currently displaying

Comment: !  http://matthewcarr.net/sample.jpg

Comment: can we understand this way... 17 pie charts have 17 different rows?.. or to be more specific what is the criteria for individual pie chart?

Comment: I'm running a stored procedure whose return lists the clients injury incidents within a given date range. The data includes the clients location or division, and what type of service provider was utilized. For instance Adult Probation used the Emergency Room  100% of the time, the Build & Dev department used the ER 50% of the time, Urgent Care 25% of the time, and an unknown service provider 25% of the time. (See sample chart)

Comment: My problem is that I am trying to make this a universal report that could be run on ANY client, one that may only have a single department, or 30 departments. So I want to be able to dynamically insert a Report Header, and a chart, for each department, based on how many departments a given client has...

Comment: The "Multiple Pie Chart" type in crystal reports works great, it just doesn't seem to allow me to set it to auto-grow to multiple pages when the chart count gets too high, and the charts are rendered too small and tightly packed. I would like to have a single chart per page, not 17 (or 30) on a single page.

Comment: To directly answer your question, On change of Department, Provider - Show value(s) Count of Provider as %

Comment: I would suggest you to not to touch the report header part instead group by department provider and place the charts in group footer and check the output

Comment: Thank you Siva! This was just the hint I was looking for. Got it working.

Comment: glad it worked for you